# How to avoid nullpointer exception on compiling pl/java?

Tags: java, maven, pljava

I'm trying to build pljava sources on Linux Mint 17 Qiana (32bit) with maven 3.2.5, JDK 1.7.0_72-b14, gpp is installed (2.24) and all modules are compiled fine except one: pl/java server side library.
The stacktrace is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.1.0:nar-compile (default-nar-compile) on project pljava-so: Execution default-nar-compile of goal com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.1.0:nar-compile failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.1.0:nar-compile (default-nar-compile) on project pljava-so: Execution default-nar-compile of goal com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.1.0:nar-compile failed.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-nar-compile of goal com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.1.0:nar-compile failed.
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:143)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 19 moreCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.github.maven_nar.cpptasks.gcc.GppLinker.isClang(GppLinker.java:317)
at com.github.maven_nar.cpptasks.gcc.GppLinker.addImpliedArgs(GppLinker.java:159)
at com.github.maven_nar.cpptasks.compiler.CommandLineLinker.createConfiguration(CommandLineLinker.java:153)
at com.github.maven_nar.cpptasks.compiler.AbstractLinker.createConfiguration(AbstractLinker.java:83)
at com.github.maven_nar.cpptasks.ProcessorDef.createConfiguration(ProcessorDef.java:200)
at com.github.maven_nar.cpptasks.CCTask.collectExplicitObjectFiles(CCTask.java:500)
at com.github.maven_nar.cpptasks.CCTask.execute(CCTask.java:647)
at com.github.maven_nar.NarCompileMojo.createLibrary(NarCompileMojo.java:433)
at com.github.maven_nar.NarCompileMojo.narExecute(NarCompileMojo.java:107)
at com.github.maven_nar.AbstractNarMojo.execute(AbstractNarMojo.java:329)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
... 20 more[ERROR][ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.[ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems like it's a bug with the MOJO.  You may want to talk to the plugin vendor about that.

Comment: that issue seems to be fixed : https://github.com/maven-nar/cpptasks-parallel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/maven_nar/cpptasks/gcc/GppLinker.java#L304 please update this plugin's version

Comment: The same result. I changed the version of nar-maven-plugin to 3.2.3.SNAPSHOT and now the NullPointer exception is on 321 line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Debian) this problem has been solved by installing the `g++` package.

I have found this workaround [here](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/issues/147).

Quote:

> I tracked the problem in GppLinker.isClang which is trying to invoke "g++ --version". Since this is a new VM, I was still in the process of determining what needed to be installed. In this case, I hadn't yet installed the gcc-c++ package to get g++.

Note: The sources I was compiling have been checked out at 2015-04-01.